# Code Editor control for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am aware of the Rich Text box controls, but I'd like to know if there are any controls I can use for users to enter C# code (with intellisense if possible)?

Thanks!

EDIT: Still looking for one

Comment: There's nothing that cool(/scary) out there right now. What were you hoping to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense in a browser is a real, real tall glass of water to pour. But there are some decent syntax highlight options out there -- I'm partial to [MarkItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) myself.

Comment: MarkItUp doesn't appear to support C#